# An idiom for a "new beginning"

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

I am looking an idiom that describes **new beginning**.

For example if someone failed in any task and is going to start it again from beginning, with new plan.

Answer (score 3):

**Back to the drawing board.**

ie, create a new plan / idea and start again.

Answer (score 2):

Start again [from scratch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from-scratch)

*from the beginning, without using anything that already exists*

Comment: Also: FROM THE GROUND UP....FROM THE WORD GO....